# How to groupby year with respect to member in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is my members table

| member | Year | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vinoth | 2015 | 1000 |
| Vinoth | 2016 | 1000 |
| Vinoth | 2016 | 300 |
| Prabu | 2015 | 1000 |
| Prabu | 2016 | 1000 |
| Ravanan | 2016 | 100 |
| Vinoth | 2016 | 3000 |
| Vinoth | 2016 | 3000 |

I want to write a Laravel eloquent that should give the output like the following

Expected Output is:

| member | Year | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vinoth | 2015 | 1000 |
| Vinoth | 2016 | 7300 |
| Prabu | 2015 | 1000 |
| Prabu | 2016 | 1000 |
| Ravanan | 2016 | 100 |

I tried the following:

```php
Member::select('SUM(amount) as amount', 'year', 'member')->groupby('year')->get();
```

Please help me to get the expected output

Comment: What is the actual output of your query? You've shown your source, expected output and query, but not your actual results, so it's impossible for us to determine what is wrong with your approach...

Answer (score 0):

For your logic to work, you should both group by the year and the member. For using sum in select statements you should use `DB::raw()`. The following should give the result you are expecting.

```
Member::select('year', 'member', DB::raw('SUM(amount) as amount'))
    ->groupBy('year', 'member')
    ->get();
```